# How to export functions from a module to be tested with npm jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, module, jestjs, tdd

**Overall Problem:** I'm very early in my learning of TDD. I am so far using npm and jest to run my tests. I have a test script that was working just fine with 2 dummy functions written as both explicit, named functions and written as factory functions. However, I am trying to write more code where I wrap most of my functions in modules to keep them more organized and *I'm not able to get jest to test the function inside of my module for some reason.*

**What I expected:**

```
$npm run test main.test.js
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
```

**What I get instead:**

```
$npm run test main.test.js

TypeError: "TypeError: test2module.test2 is not a function"
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       2 failed, 1 passed, 3 total
```

**The main.js test code:**

```
//this code passes the test
const test1=(text)=>{
    text += " and goofy";
    return text;
}

//this module and the fucntion inside of it is the one I'm having trouble with. 
const test2module = (()=>{
    const test2 = (num) =>{
        let myNum = num;
        myNum ++;
        return myNum;
    };

    return {test2};
})
    



//no code beyond this line
module.exports = {test1, test2module};
```

**The main.test.js test code:**

```
const {test1, test2module} = require("./main");

test("does test1 add goofy?",()=>{
    expect(test1("donald")).toBe('donald and goofy');

});

describe("does test2 increment?", ()=> {
    test("6 should become 7", () =>{
        expect(test2module.test2(6)).toBe(7);
    });

    test("1 should become 2", () => {
        expect(test2module.test2(1)).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** the test2module was missing another set of (); at the end of it. So it wasn't actually fully written out and I think this created a syntax error.

Code runs and passes test just fine when you actually close the function:

```
const test2module = (()=>{
    const test2 = (num) =>{
        let myNum = num;
        myNum ++;
        return myNum;
    };

    return {test2};
})();
```

Sure enough, I solved it as I was writing out the question. (Gotta love rubber ducks).
Rather than delete all my work, I figured I'd post it anyway with the answer just in case someone else has this specific problem in the future.